# SQL to loop through data and create new columns that contain the previous x days data

Tags: sql

Looking to manipulate some data that currently looks like

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| ID |    Date     | Volume |
+----+-------------+--------+
| 1  | 01/01/2017  |      4 |
| 1  | 04/01/2017  |     10 |
| 1  | 03/01/2017  |     13 |
| 3  | 01/01/2017  |     13 |
| 4  | 03/01/2017  |     12 |
| 4  | 05/01/2017  |      3 |
| 4  | 08/01/2017  |      2 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

Into something that has new columns that looks at the previous 7 days worth volumes for that specific ID & Date (also including 0s where there is no data present). I'm assuming I would loop through the IDs and Dates but I am struggling to get my head round it. Any help would be much appreciated

```
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | Date       | Volume | Date - 1 | Date - 2 | Date - 3 | Date - 4 | Date - 5 | Date - 6 | Date - 7 |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 01/01/2017 | 4      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 04/01/2017 | 10     | 13       | 0        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 03/01/2017 | 13     | 0        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3  | 01/01/2017 | 13     | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4  | 03/01/2017 | 12     | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4  | 05/01/2017 | 3      | 0        | 12       | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4  | 08/01/2017 | 2      | 0        | 0        | 3        | 0        | 12       | 0        | 0        |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: how about subquery?

Comment: maybe 7 joins on date = date -1 to 7?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Or is it required to be ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, The id and date combination of columns should be unique to use this. 'Date-1' work for oracle relevant function should call for other databases.

```
SELECT s.id,
s.Date,
s.Volume ,
(SELECT Volume FROM table1 WHERE id = s.id AND Date= s.Date-1
),
(SELECT Volume FROM table1 WHERE id = s.id AND Date= s.Date-2
)
FROM table1 s
```